# Windows hello with pin when logging to Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-edge, windows-hello

I'm trying to log into Edge browser to access my saved profile (bookmarks etc). I know the email, password, I have 2FA. I can log in on microsoft.com, etc.

When I log into edge it asks for a pin. I don't have the pin, at home it never asked for a pin. I am travelling and the machine the windows is installed to is thousands of miles away, so none of the 'just disable it in windows' solutions is valid, the current machine I'm on doesn't have it enabled. When I log in to microsoft.com, the home machine is one of the devices paired with the account.

How do I move forward, so I can log in with any of the other secure login methods? Any option I found so far requires access to the windows 10 machine; which again is thousands of miles away. I don't even get why it even asks for a pin.

I tried password reset, literally every clickable button or link as part of edge profile login. Last idea I have is remove the home machine from the Microsoft account, but uncertain what chaos that will do to it, once I'm back home. What now? I'm lost. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: How was Windows Hello configured on the home PC? TPM, hardware key, Pin (or passphrase), etc.?

Comment: Add a PIN.   That is normally (always in my case) asked for before setting up Hello, so you probably already have a PIN.

Comment: Asked the initial question without complications, but the person having problem is actually my parent. He has the PC at home installed, never needs to log in with PIN or Password. I would assume he has the hello camera thing log him in.
Any password he could have possibly used on it he exhausted already and doesn't recall ever having to enter a PIN.
He is using my PC. My pc has no relation to his account at all. Just want to log him into edge with his own profile so he can browse as usual. I'm just baffled why this is so complicated, considering his acc can be accessed just fine on MS site.

Comment: You should be looking at the Hello settings on the computer. There should be options to change/reset the PIN there.

Comment: There is no pin or windows hello set on the computer I'm trying to log in on to Edge. The computer that has Windows Hello is on a different continent. not accessible.

Is there no way to get rid of this junk windows hello even though I have access to the account in all other manner?